# How to limit tap on BottomNavigatioView item to only once, to not reload fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

How can I limit a tap on a BottomNavigatioView item to just once, so that my mapfragment doesn't have to reload itself when someone spamms the item?

My current Solution is this one:

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.World:
                if (!(currentFragment instanceof MapsFragment)) {
                fragment = new MapsFragment();
                    }
                break;

            case R.id.Friends:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                break;


            case R.id.Chats:
                fragment = new You_Fragment();
                break;
        }
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
        return true;
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work since the fragment throws a Nullpointer.

What can i change to achieve the above?

Comment: which line is throwin null pointer ?

Comment: transaction.replace since fragment is null on 2nd tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this! Worked for me:

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.World:
            if (currentFragment instanceof MapsFragment) {

                return false;

            } else {

                fragment = new MapsFragment();

            }
            break;

        case R.id.Friends:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            break;


        case R.id.Chats:
            fragment = new You_Fragment();
            break;
    }
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
    return true;
    }
});
```